# confusing getchar using read() under linux

Tags: c, pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

1. Why do we write *bufp = buf since both are arrays so in my opinion it should be:

   ```
   static char bufp = buf;
   ```
2. How does *bufp "know" from which position to start displaying ? It is not initialized to zero in any way. After assigning `buf` to `bufp` I'd expect that in return line it starts with the last entered char.
3. Is unsigned char modifier used here just to omit the case of `-1` being the input - meaning `EOF` on most systems?

```
#include "syscalls.h"
/* getchar: simple buffered version */
int getchar(void)
{
    static char buf[BUFSIZ];
    static char *bufp = buf; /* [1] */
    static int n = 0;
    if (n == 0) {            /* buffer is empty */
        n = read(0, buf, sizeof buf);
        bufp = buf;          /* ? [1] here it is written like in my question so which is true ? */
    }
    return (--n >= 0) ? (unsigned char) *bufp++ : EOF; /* [2] & [3] */
}
```

Comment: If You still look at this post, can You please check my comment under ring0 answer? I have a problem with output there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] `char bufp = buf` is incorrect, as buf is an array of char (and is internally an address, i.e. the content of a pointer), and `char bufp` would declare a unique character. `char *bufp`, instead, is a pointer to a char (to the first char, but you can access the next ones also).

[2] `bufp` points to the `buf` array, ie its first character, at the beginning. And `n` is set to `0`. `bufp`, `buf` and `n` are all static, meaning they "live" after the function returns - each of their value is initialized when the program loads, then the initialization is not performed anymore each time the function is called. Thus they "remember" the status of the buffer:

```
`n` is the number of characters in the buffer, ready to be returned one by one,

`bufp` points to the next character to be returned (when n > 0),

and `buf` the array just holds the characters in the buffer.
```

So to answer your [2] question,

- when there is no character available (n == 0) a call to `read` fills the buffer `buf` and `bufp` points to the beginning of that array.
- then as long as the buffer characters have not all been returned one by one (n > 0), `*bufp` is the next character to be returned ; `*bufp++` gives the character to be returned and increments the `bufp` pointer by one.

[3] The `unsigned` modifier prevents the compiler to propagate the `*bufp` character (8 bits) sign to the `int` other bytes (usually 32 bits, ie the 24 most significant bits), since an `int` is returned. Thus any character where code would be > 127 (for unsigned chars, or  negative for signed char) is returned as is (eg (unsigned char)200 is returned as (int)200).

Comment: Thank You! After fixing a problem with "syscalls.h" - including unistd.h instead, I have a problem in seeing output. Program simply produces NO output. Do You know how to fix it? Here is the code: [link](http://ideone.com/LWMC5)

Comment: It does not produce any output because it only reads. In main(), you should call getchax in a loop and printf its return value until you read EOF. Something along the lines of `char c; do { c = getchax(); printf("%c",c); } while (c != EOF);`

Comment: `EOF` is not a char. See http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1048865140 for explanations, and the first example to display characters (`fgetc(fp)` may be replaced with `getchar()`).

Answer (score 1):

`buf` is an array, so it is not of type char, but of type char *.

`char *bufp` declares that bufp is also of type `char *`. Generically, the two approaches below are similar:

```
char *bufp = buf;   // Declare and assign in a single line

char *bufp;   // Declare
bufp = buf;   // Then assign
```

Because of the `static` modifier, only the first option is possible in your example.

`bufp` is a pointer that has the same value of `buf`, i.e., `buf` is the address of the first element in `buf[BUFSIZ]`. `bufp` also points to this address. So `bufp` "knows" everything that "buf" knows. You can even use something like `bufp[n]` as far as `n` is not out of range.

In summary, buf[BUFSIZ] is an array whose address is `buf`, or `&buf[0]`, or `bufp` or `&bufp[0]`.

EOF is not necessarily the same in all systems, hence the last line makes sure that things are consistent.